# After adding column and dropping that column, i can face some issue related to Database!

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I tried to add Time Stamp column on some tables under this issue. But some fatal errors came out after adding Time Stamp. Because I just create column without setting on either foreign key or primary key.

> Anyway, i drop that column but i can face some issues.

I have some simple products on website, when i try to add them to cart but i see the error sql messages

[image]

What causes this problem? I even delete the column under the issue !

Answer (score 0):

Check out `WHERE` clause in this SQL:

```
WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '9') 
  AND (()) 
  AND (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1')
```

There is empty `AND` which is invalid. Check or post the code that creates the collection. I assume that you were using this column in the where clause in a way that now it is not appended.